# DKIM only filters from pine, not php mail

Tags: php, sendmail, alpine-mail, dkim

I've setup DKIM filters by following the steps on this page:
http://blog.mixu.net/2009/11/03/setting-up-spf-senderid-and-dkim-on-centos-5-3-using-sendmail/

I've verified that DKIM Signature headers are being sent with my emails when I test by sending an email from alpine on the server, to my gmail.

However, when using php's mail() function to send an email from this server, the DKIM headers are not being added.

I looked into my /var/log/maillog file, and that is indeed the case.
I would see this:
 dkim-filter[...]: ..."DKIM-Signature" header added
When I send an email from alpine, but not when I send an email from my php script.

What do I need to configure to make it work from php mail() also?

Thank you

Comment: Found more details after some research. Basically alpine uses sendmail with these flags by default:  
`sendmail -bs -odb -oem`  
While php's mail config wants to use something like:  
`sendmail -t -i`

The difference is in the `-bs`, which puts sendmail in SMTP protocol mode. When sendmail is invoked using this mode, the DKIM milter gets triggered correctly. Otherwise, DKIM milter does not get triggered.

Comment: That said, I still don't know why DKIM milter does not sign when using `sendmail -t`. Currently I would have to work around this by writing my own PHP wrapper that uses `sendmail -bs` because PHP's mail() by default can't handle it. Would still appreciate help on this.